# Declare a bundled plugin as a dependency in IntelliJ IDEA Plugin

Tags: intellij-plugin

Non bundled plugins are stored in [the repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/) and can be referenced by `groupId:artifactId:versionId` but [the documentation](https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/plugin_structure/plugin_dependencies.html) only says this ambiguous thing about declaring dependencies on bundled plugins:

> locate the plugin’s main JAR file containing `META-INF/plugin.xml`
> descriptor with  tag (or  if not specified).

Okay. Locate it and do what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to copy the template for a gradle IntelliJ plugin and copy [this example](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/blob/master/examples/plugin-with-dependencies/build.gradle) which led me to declare the dependency by plugin name with no version, groupId. In my case I wanted to use classes from the built-in maven plugin so I added this to the plugins = [....]. The plugin will automatically grab the version of that plugin that is in your IntelliJ.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.intellij' version '0.4.26'
}

group 'com.whatever'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
id 'MyPlugin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    runtime files('maven.jar', 'libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    runtime fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

// See https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/
intellij {
    version '2020.2.2'
    plugins = ['maven']
}

patchPluginXml {
    changeNotes """
      Add change notes here.<br>
      <em>most HTML tags may be used</em>"""
}
```